# Responsive Website

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have a project to create website, but i make it manually not using bootstrap.
The problem is when i zoom in and zoom out, it's not responsive..
so, how to create a responsive website in any type screen and when i zoom in/zoom out??
Here is my css code

body{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}

```
.wadah{
    width:83.8%;
    height:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:650px;
    left:102px;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid #d2d1d1}
.top-news{
    width: 1125px;
    height:220px;
    background:#;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d2d1d1}
.top-news-inside{
    width:281.25px;
    height:220px;
    float:left;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:#;
    }
.content{
    width:1125px;
    height:auto;
    background:#}
.content-left{

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with CSS3 you can use some media queries:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

You just have to choose suitable breakpoints and rewrite your current style. For example you can add all elements with `float: left` rule the `float: none` property in media queries and extend their width to `100%` of the screen (you can probably make this changes to your `top-news-inside` class). This will break your site into columns.

To control floating elements please be sure you use `clear: both` rule:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Provide me the jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

add this to header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
```

create a css file like responsive.css

for making responsive you should change your css codes for different size

for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.wadah{
    height:200px;
    top:350px;
    left:52px;
}
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.wadah{
    height:400px;
    top:500px;
    left:80px;
}
}
```

*** The larger size should be higher ***

with this you can do more than changing size (like changing color or making mobile navbar)

I hope this is useful

Sorry for bad english :D