# How to get my page to be responsive for all devices?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my first post here. I am fairly new to coding. I am trying to get my page to be responsive and size according to the the device it is viewed on. Right now, it is only appearing very small in the top right corner of any browser. Does anyone have any advice as to how I can adjust this?

Here is the code for my page.

Thank you for any help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="wdith=device-width, intital-scale=1"/>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/ps-logo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!-- Font -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>ER</title>
<style type="text/css">
     #header{
    min-height: 100px;
  }

#body{
  min-height: 400px;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

body{
  min-height: 400px;
  /*background-color: #0d1121;*/
  background-color: #151922;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
 }

div{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.banner{
  display: inline-block;
}

/*Dots
.loading span{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: dots;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}

.loading span:nth-child(2){
  background-color: lightgray;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.loading span:nth-child(3){
  background-color: gray;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes dots{
  50%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.7) translateY(10px);
  }
}
*/

section{
  cursor: pointer;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
}

h1{
  font-size: 30px;
}

.title{
  margin-top: -18px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.inline-block{
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.phone{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.email{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.linkedin{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.web{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
  filter: contrast(50%);
  -webkit-filter: contrast(50%);
}

.link{
color: white;
}

.inline-block{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: -1px;
}

.icon:hover{
  filter: contrast(50%);
  -webkit-filter: contrast(50%);
}

/*landing page*/

.preload{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #151922;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.airplane{
  height: 200px;
  animation: airplane 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.preload h3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  transform: translateY(-75%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: -100px;
}

.preload-finish{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes airplane{
  from{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Preloader -->
    <section class="preload">
        <img class="icon airplane" src="img/aeroplane-white.png" alt="airplane">
        <h3>You are arriving...</h3>

    <!-- Dots -->
    <div class="loading">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    </section>

<header id="header">
    <!-- Erjana's Headshot -->
        <p class="banner">
            <a class="erjana" href="mailto:@.com">
                <img src="img/era.jpg" alt="headshot" width="100" height="132">
            </a>
        </p>

    <!-- PS Logo -->
        <p class="banner">
            <a href="https://#.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/ps-logo-blue.jpeg" alt="https://#.com/" width="150" height="164">
            </a>
        </p>
    
</header>

<div id="body">
    <section>
        <h1>ER</h1>
        <p class="title">Director of Human Resources</p>
        <a class="link" href="tel:+#">O: #</a> <br>
        <a class="link" href="tel:+#">C: #</a> <br>
        <a class="link" href="mailto:@.com">@.com</a> <br>
        <a class="link" href="https://#.com/" target="_blank">#.com</a>
    </section>

    <!-- Phone -->
    <section class="inline-block">
        <p class="phone inline-block">
            <a class="icon inline-block" href="tel:+#">
                <img alt="Phone" src="img/call-white.png">
            </a>
        </p>

    <!-- Email -->
        <p class="email inline-block">
            <a class="icon inline-block" href="mailto:@.com">
                <img alt="Email" src="img/email-white.png">
            </a>
        </p>

    <!-- LinkedIn -->
        <p class="linkedin inline-block">
            <a class="icon inline-block" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/X/" target="_blank">
                <img alt="LinkedIn" src="img/linkedin-white.png">
            </a>
        </p>

    <!-- Website -->
        <p class="web inline-block">
            <a class="icon inline-block" href="https://#.com/" target="_blank">
                <img alt="Website" src="img/web-white.png">
            </a>
        </p>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

<footer>
    
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: read about media queries.

Comment: Pls keep the punctuations, grammar and spellings right when you are posting something here. It would be better if you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will give you detailed explanation on how to ask good questions. Also pls keep appropriate [Title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554433/responsive-website)

Answer (score 2):

I see your problem, I think you should to use a **media query** for responsive all devices. Check it here my media query... it as simple just put your CSS here, which devices you want to change something.

```
/* Normal desktop :1200px. */
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1500px) {

/*     put your css */
}


/* Normal desktop :992px. */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

  /*     put your css */
}

 
/* Tablet desktop :768px. */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

  /*     put your css */
}

 
/* small mobile :320px. */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

 /*     put your css */
  
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is a front-end framework that fits your needs nicely. It implements a "Column" scaffolding block that orients elements differently depending on screen size.

Comment: I'm not sure it's wise learning bootstrap without having fundamental knowledge of CSS, it's possible but ultimately more troublesome in case OP would like to customize their website or try to understand why bootstrap or ultimately any other framework works the way it does